# How to wait until app is loaded after nativescript firebus push notification received

Tags: angular, firebase, push-notification, nativescript

i am making angular nativescript app with push notifications. I do receive push notification and onPushTokenReceivedCallback is called. on message received I want to redirect user to certain tab however redirection is not always working. If i wrap to 2s timeout all works. But this is not how it shuppose to be done. Mu guess that there is should be some pointer when app is loaded and postpone message handling untill then.

Any advices on common practice how to handle such situation?

Comment: Where exactly you are adding the callback? You may add the message received callback at onInit of app component, so you won't have to use any timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I was using lazyloading of other tabs. So i have created observable navigation which gets triggered after loading of module finished. Now everything works fine.